# how to call css class into javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried to use the plugin for select, but the css plugin class not working when i'm insert the class inside javascript :

plugin i want use using javascript :

```
 $('.search-test').SumoSelect({
    search: true,
    searchText: 'Please enter the appropriate keywords...',
    noMatch: 'Sorry, the data you are looking for is not found, please enter the appropriate keywords, the data you are looking for: "{0}"',
    // up: false
});
```

javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;

    $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += "<td>"+"<select class='search-test' id='search-test'><option>a</option></select>" + "</td>";
        html += '</tr>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event) {

        var form_data = $(this).serialize();

        if (error == '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "request/create",
                method: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 'ok') {
                        $('#item_table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
                        $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success background-success">Success insert the data!</div>');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#error').html('<div  class="alert alert-danger background-danger">' + error + '</div>');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Doesn't style apply to you select element?

Comment: when i call the class, css design for SumoSelect plugin is not working

Comment: Have you checked the style file. Does it load correctly?

Comment: yes i have check it but is doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved, I was careless in placing version of jquery.min.js